# Fetching files from remote server - Perl/Unix

Tags: perl, unix

In regards to the [question](https://superuser.com/questions/416858/get-all-files-created-in-past-24-hours-unix/416865#416865) I previously posted, I have written the following script to load a specific file:

```
#!/bin/perl

use strict;
use Net::FTP;

my $ftpOb = Net::FTP->new("X")
         or die ("Could not connect to the FTP Server: $@");
print "Connected \n";

$ftpOb->login("A", "B")
         or die ("Incorrect server credentials");
print "Logged in \n";

print " Current folder is: " . $ftpOb->pwd();

$ftpOb->cwd("root/Folder") or die ("Cannot connect to the folder on Server");
print "Transferred to folder \n";


$ftpOb->get("621418185-006249189002-5383.txt")
         or die ("Error occured while fetching the file");

$ftpOb->quit;
```

However, the code seems to fail to change the working directory and I get the following output:

```
Connected
Logged in
Cannot connect to the folder on Server at ./GetUploadFile.pl line 16.
 Current folder is: /
```

Can anyone please help me debug the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include `$ftpOb->message()`  in your error messages (except for the connect, where `$@` is the correct error message).

Also do a dir() and list what files/directories are available.